# How to make all font glyphs more bold automatically in FontForge?

Tags: fonts, font-forge

Take for example this Tibetan script:

[image]

This, and every font I have found online for Tibetan (except for Google Noto) does *not* come in bold. But some I really like the shape of. I was wondering if there is an easy way to take any of the fonts and make it bold.

Comment: "Creating a bold version of a font can be rapidly approximated by running a filter called Change weight, found in he Element > Styles menu" ([source](http://designwithfontforge.com/en-US/Bold_and_Other_Weights.html))